# Same order number for different orders

Tags: magento2

We added prefix for order number from db, and now because of this orders has same numbers for different store views. How can we have always unique and incremented order number for all store views?

[image]

We are using magento 2.4

Thx for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be adding different prefixes per each store view.

Let's take my example - I have 2 websites, and one of them has 2 store views. By checking my db, I have:

```sql
mysql> select * from sales_sequence_meta where entity_type='order';
+---------+-------------+----------+------------------+
| meta_id | entity_type | store_id | sequence_table   |
+---------+-------------+----------+------------------+
|       1 | order       |        0 | sequence_order_0 |
|       5 | order       |        1 | sequence_order_1 |
|       9 | order       |        2 | sequence_order_2 |
|      13 | order       |        3 | sequence_order_3 |
+---------+-------------+----------+------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

As you can see, I have an entry for the 'order' entity for each of my storeviews.

Now I go to the table that holds the prefixes, I have:

```sql
mysql> select * from sales_sequence_profile where meta_id in (select meta_id from sales_sequence_meta where entity_type='order');
+------------+---------+--------+--------+-------------+------+------------+---------------+-----------+
| profile_id | meta_id | prefix | suffix | start_value | step | max_value  | warning_value | is_active |
+------------+---------+--------+--------+-------------+------+------------+---------------+-----------+
|          1 |       1 | NULL   | NULL   |           1 |    1 | 4294967295 |    4294966295 |         1 |
|          5 |       5 | NULL   | NULL   |           1 |    1 | 4294967295 |    4294966295 |         1 |
|          9 |       9 | 2      | NULL   |           1 |    1 | 4294967295 |    4294966295 |         1 |
|         13 |      13 | 3      | NULL   |           1 |    1 | 4294967295 |    4294966295 |         1 |
+------------+---------+--------+--------+-------------+------+------------+---------------+-----------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

As you can see here, the 'prefix' can be different for each store view. My default store and the main store view don't have any prefixes, but my 2 storeviews under the same store have prefixes and they differ.

So basically, you can update the prefix independently for each store view.

Also, check this article https://bsscommerce.com/blog/complete-tutorial-guide-change-order-number-magento-2/, it should make more sense after you read it.

Comment: Many thanks for the quick response! We tried your approach and it worked superb. However our marketing team still want to have unique incremented order numbers even for different stores. Can it be achieved in M2 without any complications ? It was possible on Magento 1.

Comment: hi there, glad i was able to assist you :) for the unique incremented order numbers, i think this will have to do with setting starting values independently on each store, let me throw one more link https://www.classyllama.com/blog/m2-incrementid (check section **Minimum increment-ID number**) this will explains what's going on. I haven't tried this, but i am sure that with some time allocated to this you will find the correct settings for your setup. Cheers!